# How to get the number of items in Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex3

I am using Datagrid control in flex.

I need to get the count of number of items in that Datagrid. What is the method to get that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the number of items by checking the data provider for the data grid:

```
var count:Number = (myDataGrid.dataProvider as ICollectionView).length;
```

Per the documentation, data sources assigned to the data provider either implement ICollectionView already, and if they don't, they are changed to a class that does implement ICollectionView.

Comment: I had the same question before I found this post. I had tried using .dataProviderLength but it did not work. Any idea why?

Comment: If you were trying to use `rowCount` and wasn't working... this is the way. So intuituive.